# Rota para relacionamento Many-to-Many

Tags: laravel, api, rest, back-end

tenho uma pergunta relacionada API REST, se alguém puder ajudar, muito obrigado.

Tenho 2 entidades, Product e Store, que tem um relacionamento many-to-many entre elas. Um Product pode estar em disponível em 1 ou mais Stores e, por sua vez, uma Store pode ter 1 ou mais Products. Até aí, beleza.

Porém preciso de uma rota exclusiva para adicionar um Product numa Store e também uma rota exclusiva para remover um Product de uma Store. O relacionamento é simples, não tem nenhuma coluna extra na pivot table.

Qual abordagem vocês usariam?

Mais uma vez, obrigado.

Comment: não acredito ser uma boa ideia modelar a aplicação baseada no front :|